# PubNub and Parse with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, messaging, pubnub

I would like to integrate PubNub with Parse to create a messaging application.. But PubNub's documentation does not include code for the communication between Parse and PubNub.

Comment: If you understand any Objective-C it can be simple enough to translate one to the other. If you get stuck on something in particular I recommend posting a bit of code on stackoverflow and asking for help in translating it.

Comment: I can easily translate it.. I'll update my question. The docs do include any code for communicating between Parse and PubNub

Comment: Parse CloudCode will be easier to start with.  Note that the PubNub Swift SDK is still under construction.

Comment: Cool story bro - [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question at all.  Stack Overflow is not intended to be used for managing your project task list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub and Parse Realtime Collaboration Sync

Here are a few resources that will help you get started with PubNub and Parse.  Note that we have an officially supported [PubNub Parse Cloud Code SDK](https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/tree/add-parse-support/parse) to help simplify your integration needs.

1. [Realtime Collaboration Sync with Parse API and PubNub `tutorial`](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-collaboration-sync-parse-api-pubnub/)
2. [How do I publish a message from Parse?  `community`](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/293/how-do-i-publish-a-message-from-parse)
3. [PubNub JavaScript SDK for Parse.com CloudCode platform `beta`](https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/tree/add-parse-support/parse)
4. [PubNub Swift `resources`](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/tag/swift/)
5. [PubNub HTTP REST on Mashape `api`](https://www.mashape.com/pubnub/pubnub-network)